# Chrome is not opening magnet links properly with deluge?

Tags: 15.04, deluge, xdg-open

If I use firefox, and click a magnet link, everything runs smoothly.  however, in google chrome, all I get is that the deluge icon shakes as if it is opening something, but when I look at the window I don't see anything coming up.  Any help?

After upgrading to ubuntu 15.10, it looks like this issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

`xdg-mime default deluge.desktop x-scheme-handler/magnet` This command in the terminal should fix your problem

Comment: Thanks for the help!  but no luck.  I no longer have a wiggling icon, strangely, but the torrent's information doesn't come up in the window that opens, all that happens is that the program starts.